# DB function failed with error number 1 in joomla admin panel

Tags: joomla1.5

When i access joomla article manager or module manager then i had faced the bellow output:
500 - An error has occurred!

DB function failed with error number 1
Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_57c0_0.MYD' (Errcode: 17) SQL=SELECT c.*, g.name AS groupname, cc.title AS name, u.name AS editor, f.content_id AS frontpage, s.title AS section_name, v.name AS author FROM jos_content AS c LEFT JOIN jos_categories AS cc ON cc.id = c.catid LEFT JOIN jos_sections AS s ON s.id = c.sectionid LEFT JOIN jos_groups AS g ON g.id = c.access LEFT JOIN jos_users AS u ON u.id = c.checked_out LEFT JOIN jos_users AS v ON v.id = c.created_by LEFT JOIN jos_content_frontpage AS f ON f.content_id = c.id WHERE c.state != -2 ORDER BY section_name , section_name, cc.title, c.ordering LIMIT 0, 20

Answer (score 0):

You are having problem with database. Reasons are as follows:

1. You do not have permission to certain table/action
2. Once of the tables is corrupt, you need to REPAIR it.

Answer (score 0):

Open up phpMyAdmin, select the database, click the checkbox on that table (jos_content).  Scroll down to the bottom of the page, and in the select box select "Repair" that should solve your problem